# Rails console truncates the Activerecord output - How to prevent truncating?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to get all my user's email from the production rails console. Problem is the emails are being cut off when they are long:

```
User.select('email').where(:guest => false) 


#<User email: "app+11rmqcgg9q.1d74111.6c2e294218ddadfff033de3f5bb3...">
```

How can I run the command in rails c and not have rails truncate the output? I just want a CSV of emails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
puts User.select('email').where(:guest => false).map(&:email).join("\n")
```

Answer (score 5):

It's the output of [inspect](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/inspect/class). So overriding it should be enough. If you care only about the emails in that situation you could actually get it like:

```
User.where(:guest => false).map(&:email)
```